# Postgresql memory leak in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, memory-leaks, pycharm, connection

I am working on a python project where I am receiving some large data from a database based on some queries. However, I realized that memory usage grows more and more in every iteration.

I realized that even if I comment out everything after `cur.fetchall()` the returned data remains in the memory.

For example

```
def call_gc_and_print_out():
    gc.collect()
    print("BEG:", psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info())
    print("--------------------------------------------------")
    print(gc.get_stats())
    print("--------------------------------------------------")


try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user, host=host, password=password)
    for q in queries:
        call_gc_and_print_out()
        cur = conn.cursor("cursor_name")
        rows = fetchall()
        gc.collect()
except Exception as ex: 
    print(ex)
finally:
    conn.commit()
    conn.close
```

uses pretty much the same amount as the following

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user, host=host, password=password)
    for q in queries:
        call_gc_and_print_out()
        cur = conn.cursor("cursor_name")
        rows = fetchall()
        # process rows 
        # store at some_var
        # push to the database
        # delete some_var
        gc.collect()
except Exception as ex: 
    print(ex)
finally:
    conn.commit()
    conn.close
```

Here is an example of memory usage and garbage collector stats after some iterations for the second code:

Here are memory and garbage collector stats for a local run for 50 test images:

```
First iterations
BEG: pmem(rss=851664896, vms=6933315584, pfaults=211942, pageins=0)
--------------------------------------------------
[{'collections': 321, 'collected': 5172, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 29, 'collected': 816, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 3, 'collected': 147, 'uncollectable': 0}]
--------------------------------------------------

2nd
BEG: pmem(rss=857223168, vms=6941704192, pfaults=214551, pageins=0)
--------------------------------------------------
[{'collections': 326, 'collected': 5172, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 29, 'collected': 816, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 6, 'collected': 147, 'uncollectable': 0}]
--------------------------------------------------

10th
BEG: pmem(rss=1448996864, vms=8391995392, pfaults=1057046, pageins=0)
--------------------------------------------------
[{'collections': 2526, 'collected': 5172, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 225, 'collected': 816, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 45, 'collected': 147, 'uncollectable': 0}]
--------------------------------------------------

15th 

BEG: pmem(rss=2870161408, vms=9710194688, pfaults=5553339, pageins=0)
--------------------------------------------------
[{'collections': 14708, 'collected': 5172, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1329, 'collected': 816, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 140, 'collected': 147, 'uncollectable': 0}]
--------------------------------------------------

20th
BEG: pmem(rss=3235741696, vms=10012725248, pfaults=9513214, pageins=0)
--------------------------------------------------
[{'collections': 25938, 'collected': 5172, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 2347, 'collected': 816, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 217, 'collected': 147, 'uncollectable': 0}]
--------------------------------------------------
```

I see that gc collection and memory usage are increasing.

I tried pretty much everything I found, `gc.collect()`, `adding name to cursor`, `cursor.close()`, `conn.commit(); conn.close()`, `cur.fetch one by one instead of fetchall()`, `del output_dict after every iteration`.

My questions are

1. Are the growing number of `collections` and `memory` definitely signs of memory leak, or may they be something else?
2. What tool can I use that is easy to install and understand what causes the memory leak (if 1 is correct)?
3. Should I be concerned about `pfaults` and `vms` as well?

I know, with the pseudocode I shared, it is hard to find a definitive answer (can't share the code due to NDA), but I would appreciate any suggestions.

I am using python 3.8.6 on PyCharm professional edition on Mac Catalina.

Comment: Stripping out the proprietary parts of the code while retaining the behavior in question is something which you can do, and something which we can not.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, have you found the solution to clear memory between iterations?

Comment: It has been a year, so I don't really remember the details but as far as I remember I was using `dataclasses`. That was the reason for the leakage. When I removed it, it was resolved. I can't remember why or how unfortunately. hope this helps